# Fitering a dataframe by a "string" value assigned in object column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a DF and I want to filter in to a new DF all the rows that have "TRUE" in an object typed column.
Tried to cast it to string but that didn't work.
In addition after that I neet to cast all of that column (series type) values to lowercase.

Here is my code:

```
df["valid"] = df["valid"].astype(str)
in_df = df[df.valid.lower() == "true"]
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Values in column are boolean (`True, False`) with `None`s.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'valid':[True, False, None]})
print (df)
   valid
0   True
1  False
2   None
```

Your solution should be changed by [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html):

```
in_df = df[df.valid.astype(str).str.lower() == "true"]
```

Or compare by boolean `True` value:

```
in_df = df[df.valid == True]
```

Or convert to [`Nullable Boolean data type`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html) by `.astype('boolean')`:

```
in_df = df[df.valid.astype('boolean')]
```

---

```
print (in_df)
  valid
0  True
```

Comment: Got some nan values in that column, so don't think asbool is an option. And the first one took both trues and falses.

Comment: @Blur - What is `print (df.valid.unique().tolist())` ?

Comment: [nan, True] a list of 2

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?
Not sure I got it...

Comment: @Blur - Answer was explained.